# No. of cols differ from df.info() to pd corr.matrix - Why?

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I want to create a correlation analysis and visualize the result in a Seaborn heatmap.

But somehow I seem to be getting 27 columns in my corr. matrix, but only 21 columns in my heatmap. They work with the same pandas DataFrame. Is anybody able to help 'align' these 2 outputs, so they are more credible?

I cannot give you my data, as they are classified. But I can provide the relevant part of the output-code:

```
new_df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 406590 entries, 0 to 406589
Data columns (total 27 columns):
status                                                          406590 non-null object
ZipCode                                                         406590 non-null int64
CommuneName                                                     406590 non-null object
CompanyType                                                     406590 non-null object
sectiondescription                                              406590 non-null object
Db07description                                                 406590 non-null object
FoundedDate                                                     406590 non-null int64
UpdatedAt                                                       406590 non-null object
HasSupplementaryInformationOnOtherMattersExtendedReview         406590 non-null int64
NumberOfSupplementaryInformationOnOtherMattersExtendedReview    406590 non-null int64
NumberOfNegativeEquityStreak                                    406590 non-null int64
NumberOfNegativeEquityTotal                                     406590 non-null int64
HasNegativeEquity                                               406590 non-null int64
GrossProfit                                                     211340 non-null float64
ProfitLoss                                                      404409 non-null float64
ProfitLossDeltaPercentage                                       293324 non-null float64
CurrentAssets                                                   373672 non-null float64
Assets                                                          401293 non-null float64
ContributedCapital                                              389849 non-null float64
Equity                                                          403463 non-null float64
ShorttermLiabilitiesOtherThanProvisions                         370314 non-null float64
LiabilitiesAndEquity                                            401269 non-null float64
CurrentRatio                                                    351068 non-null float64
ReturnOnInvestment                                              335243 non-null float64
Solidity                                                        389800 non-null float64
SolidityDelta                                                   288162 non-null float64
SolidityDeltaPercentage                                         286526 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(14), int64(7), object(6)
memory usage: 83.8+ MB

new_df
new_df.corr()
ZipCode FoundedDate HasSupplementaryInformationOnOtherMattersExtendedReview NumberOfSupplementaryInformationOnOtherMattersExtendedReview    NumberOfNegativeEquityStreak    NumberOfNegativeEquityTotal HasNegativeEquity   GrossProfit ProfitLoss  ProfitLossDeltaPercentage   ... Assets  ContributedCapital  Equity  ShorttermLiabilitiesOtherThanProvisions LiabilitiesAndEquity    CurrentRatio    ReturnOnInvestment  Solidity    SolidityDelta   SolidityDeltaPercentage
ZipCode 1.000000    -0.069511   0.002012    0.002012    -0.026386   -0.023624   -0.039029   -0.006337   -0.000921   -0.000053   ... -0.005082   -0.001132   -0.001403   -0.005764   -0.004654   0.001595    -0.000647   -0.001542   -0.002016   -0.002050
FoundedDate -0.069511   1.000000    0.001771    0.001771    0.075595    0.074350    0.136362    -0.034162   -0.007959   0.004283    ... -0.008046   -0.005028   -0.006730   -0.009167   -0.008307   -0.003366   -0.002030   -0.000224   0.000021    -0.000512
HasSupplementaryInformationOnOtherMattersExtendedReview 0.002012    0.001771    1.000000    1.000000    0.017882    0.018207    0.017321    -0.001370   -0.000323   0.000126    ... -0.000610   -0.000255   -0.000344   -0.000735   -0.000598   -0.000225   0.000123    0.000661    0.000321    -0.000294
NumberOfSupplementaryInformationOnOtherMattersExtendedReview    0.002012    0.001771    1.000000    1.000000    0.017882    0.018207    0.017321    -0.001370   -0.000323   0.000126    ... -0.000610   -0.000255   -0.000344   -0.000735   -0.000598   -0.000225   0.000123    0.000661    0.000321    -0.000294
NumberOfNegativeEquityStreak    -0.026386   0.075595    0.017882    0.017882    1.000000    0.901202    0.810353    -0.010813   -0.003785   0.001227    ... -0.003773   -0.000702   -0.002996   -0.003183   -0.003471   -0.001383   -0.001574   -0.024193   -0.007302   0.005404
NumberOfNegativeEquityTotal -0.023624   0.074350    0.018207    0.018207    0.901202    1.000000    0.718382    -0.012509   -0.004148   0.000812    ... -0.003571   -0.000941   -0.003279   -0.002901   -0.003262   -0.001744   -0.001196   -0.021833   -0.006061   0.005286
HasNegativeEquity   -0.039029   0.136362    0.017321    0.017321    0.810353    0.718382    1.000000    -0.013184   -0.005208   -0.001404   ... -0.004242   -0.000863   -0.003838   -0.002919   -0.003594   -0.001474   -0.005394   -0.019498   -0.008668   0.004836
GrossProfit -0.006337   -0.034162   -0.001370   -0.001370   -0.010813   -0.012509   -0.013184   1.000000    0.313382    -0.000074   ... -0.130506   -0.095524   -0.130232   -0.152877   -0.134392   0.001726    0.000117    0.000395    0.000190    -0.000176
ProfitLoss  -0.000921   -0.007959   -0.000323   -0.000323   -0.003785   -0.004148   -0.005208   0.313382    1.000000    0.000010    ... 0.379039    0.910941    0.392317    -0.098137   0.380585    0.000024    0.000285    0.000146    0.000118    -0.000072
ProfitLossDeltaPercentage   -0.000053   0.004283    0.000126    0.000126    0.001227    0.000812    -0.001404   -0.000074   0.000010    1.000000    ... 0.000016    0.000004    0.000013    -0.000008   -0.000001   0.000023    -0.007085   -0.032133   -0.000086   0.000009
CurrentAssets   -0.005511   -0.018441   -0.001189   -0.001189   -0.007721   -0.008139   -0.006999   0.092310    0.055951    -0.000039   ... 0.555020    0.178718    0.201831    0.717497    0.602365    0.000269    0.000301    0.000252    0.000141    0.000090
Assets  -0.005082   -0.008046   -0.000610   -0.000610   -0.003773   -0.003571   -0.004242   -0.130506   0.379039    0.000016    ... 1.000000    0.654815    0.459804    0.741743    0.976263    0.000031    0.000033    0.000121    0.000053    0.000014
ContributedCapital  -0.001132   -0.005028   -0.000255   -0.000255   -0.000702   -0.000941   -0.000863   -0.095524   0.910941    0.000004    ... 0.654815    1.000000    0.481378    0.180485    0.661261    0.000022    0.000013    0.000047    0.000019    -0.000013
Equity  -0.001403   -0.006730   -0.000344   -0.000344   -0.002996   -0.003279   -0.003838   -0.130232   0.392317    0.000013    ... 0.459804    0.481378    1.000000    0.391956    0.458600    0.000033    0.000029    0.000131    0.000063    -0.000017
ShorttermLiabilitiesOtherThanProvisions -0.005764   -0.009167   -0.000735   -0.000735   -0.003183   -0.002901   -0.002919   -0.152877   -0.098137   -0.000008   ... 0.741743    0.180485    0.391956    1.000000    0.768538    -0.000051   0.000050    0.000094    0.000042    0.000094
LiabilitiesAndEquity    -0.004654   -0.008307   -0.000598   -0.000598   -0.003471   -0.003262   -0.003594   -0.134392   0.380585    -0.000001   ... 0.976263    0.661261    0.458600    0.768538    1.000000    0.000007    0.000055    0.000129    0.000059    -0.000018
CurrentRatio    0.001595    -0.003366   -0.000225   -0.000225   -0.001383   -0.001744   -0.001474   0.001726    0.000024    0.000023    ... 0.000031    0.000022    0.000033    -0.000051   0.000007    1.000000    0.000011    0.000041    0.000016    -0.000014
ReturnOnInvestment  -0.000647   -0.002030   0.000123    0.000123    -0.001574   -0.001196   -0.005394   0.000117    0.000285    -0.007085   ... 0.000033    0.000013    0.000029    0.000050    0.000055    0.000011    1.000000    0.144242    0.145994    0.000021
Solidity    -0.001542   -0.000224   0.000661    0.000661    -0.024193   -0.021833   -0.019498   0.000395    0.000146    -0.032133   ... 0.000121    0.000047    0.000131    0.000094    0.000129    0.000041    0.144242    1.000000    0.734009    0.000057
SolidityDelta   -0.002016   0.000021    0.000321    0.000321    -0.007302   -0.006061   -0.008668   0.000190    0.000118    -0.000086   ... 0.000053    0.000019    0.000063    0.000042    0.000059    0.000016    0.145994    0.734009    1.000000    0.109639
SolidityDeltaPercentage -0.002050   -0.000512   -0.000294   -0.000294   0.005404    0.005286    0.004836    -0.000176   -0.000072   0.000009    ... 0.000014    -0.000013   -0.000017   0.000094    -0.000018   -0.000014   0.000021    0.000057    0.109639    1.000000
21 rows × 21 columns
```

The gist of it is that the df.info() establishes that I have 27 columns, but the correlation matrix only shows 21.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to go into details without a real understanding of the data, but from what you provided, I think this much holds:

If you look at your column types, 6 of them are of type `object`, and all of these are dropped. All of these seem to be descriptive or some other string-like object, which is clearly going to be hard to correlate meaningfully with all of your numeric variables. For instance, what would a correlation between "`CommuneName`" (if it is a string) and "`CurrentAssets`" represent?

What you could do is figure out where a correlation would make sense, and transform those variables accordingly; for instance, you could [one-hot-encode](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) some relevant variables, like `CommuneName`, so that you could perhaps see a trend between individual communes and their assets (to take the two example features I laid out above).

But you should really think about how much these corrletions will mean. For instance, I have a hard time imagining how you would correlate "`Db07description`" (which I assume is just a textual description of something), and a number, at least not with significant preprocessing of your description data to turn it into some meaningful vector. If there is no meaningful interpretation, consider dropping some variables from your current analysis (which is basically already being done for you by `.corr()`).

**[EDIT]** Just to note, just because pandas reads some of your variables as numeric, doesn't mean they have a really plausible interpretation: For instance, a zip code is an integer. Does that really mean that that integer should be interpreted as having an effect on something else if it increases or decreases? Is living in zip code `95061` better than living in `95062` *because it's value is one lower*? Better to consider something like that to be categorical, and not numeric.